# Logback DBAppender, configuring programmatically throwing exception

Tags: logback

I am trying to configure Logback' DBAppender programmatically, but don't know what's going wrong. It works fine with logback.xml configuration given below

```
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
        <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</jdbcUrl>
        <user>myuser</user>
        <password>mypwd</password>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
```

now when I'm trying to get and configure Logger in code like this

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("dbAppender");

        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

        DriverManagerConnectionSource dmcs = new DriverManagerConnectionSource();
        dmcs.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dmcs.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase");
        dmcs.setUser("myuser");
        dmcs.setPassword(mypwd);
        dmcs.setContext(lc);

        DBAppender dbapp =  (DBAppender) logger.getAppender("DB");
//it returns an appender with properties in logback.xml file
         if(dbapp != null) {
            dbapp.stop();
            dbapp.setConnectionSource(dmcs);
            dbapp.start();
         }
```

it throws exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect
    at ch.qos.logback.core.db.DBAppenderBase.start(DBAppenderBase.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender.start(DBAppender.java:96)
```

There is no way to set dialect or setGeneratedKey, what do I need to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to start your DriverManagerConnectionSource.

Adding the line...

```
dmcs.start();
```

before starting the Appender should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error (DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect)

The reason was, I have seted a wrong connection URL for DriverManagerConnectionSource. Unfortunately the logback is confusing us with a wrong error message

Comment: same for me. I was using Ezconnect URL instead of TNSname for oracle